# Choosing files saved internally on Android

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, storage, filepicker

How do I create a file picking activity in Android based on files that I've saved internally for the app? Like, the user uses my app and saves data internally to "scenario1", "scenario2", "scenario3". I want to be able to list all these options to the user and let him pick one of these files to load and populate my Android app with.

Comment: You have to make a file browser activity for internal files dir. And if you have done that you have a file browser for all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that task with the help of Intent. For details go through http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501714/Android-Use-Memory-Internal-External-And-Intent-To

I Hope this might help you

Comment: No that will not help. He asked for something else.